# How can I make input type number only 1-9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try like this :

```
<input type="number" pattern="[1-9]*" class="form-control" min="1">
```

I try input dot, it can

How can I disable dot(.) and another?

So, only 1-9

Comment: pattern does not work on input type number. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern

Comment: Just use min, max attributes of input type number. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_number.asp

Comment: No helpful answers

Comment: @Cerbrus, This is no duplicate. This is : input type number. It's different

Comment: @thanhnha1103, It's still can input dot. Should cannot input dot

Answer (score 2):

The same way you have `min`, you can add `max=9`:

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" max="9">
```

You will need to have some custom JavaScript validation (there are libraries for that) to interpret the `min` and `max` attributes for those browsers which do not support them natively.

Comment: It does not work. If I input dot(.), it can. It should not be input dot(.)

Comment: @Ionica, can you check [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833540/figure-not-rotating-as-expected#47833540) when you have time? It is about a game that you have developed. I couldn't contact you anywhere else, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the pattern attribute in html5:

```
<input type="text" name="name" pattern="[0-9]" title="Title" />
```

Comment: HTML5 supports regexes, so you could use this:

<input id="numbersOnly" pattern="[0-9.]+" type="text">
Warning: Some browsers don't support this yet.

Comment: I want to use input type number. No another