# Figure not rotating as expected?

Tags: javascript

I was using [The Tangram Square game](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/tangram) yesterday, in my Google Chrome browser, and the rotation was working perfectly (45° rotation axis).

Today, when I used the app again, it was again rotating 45 degrees, but apparently had another origin point. This is how it acts now:

[image]
[image]
What is causing this behaviour? The app was running on the same code, both days.

PS: You can check the game [here](https://ionicabizau.github.io/tangram/)

Edit: When you left click one of the figures, it rotates 45° on the left

Comment: I don't know how else to ask the question in order to fit stackoverflow's topics, but I really have no idea what's the source of the issue here. I would appreciate a hint here

Comment: Well for me left clicking does nothing, dragging works.  And click left & right and the same time seems to rotate right 45..  I've a feeling one of your cdn links has been updated and it's been badly updated,. aka.  Not versioned.  Try running also with disable cache in developer console, you might end up getting same as me.

Comment: @Keith the behaviour that you mention happens to me in Moxilla. Unfortunately, it still rotates the same way when I disable caching

Comment: @Keith I tried using the app on another laptop, and it's working there

Comment: In chrome there a errors appearing,.. eg. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of null at end (VM1395 svg.draggy.js:202)`,..  This is in you drag end event, you actually null this value here, so the next call fails. You also call drag on touchMove etc..  To me this code all seems a big mixed up.

Comment: @Keith yes, but that error only happens when you click again while dragging the figure, so it's not a very big deal

Comment: The error appears while NOT dragging, just clicking..

Comment: Can confirm that it doesn't happen in Chrome, but does in Firefox.

Comment: @Keith hm that's weird, cause the implementation is so that the rotation event only happens when not dragging.